# Use same user credentials on multiple different Laravel install?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, single-sign-on

**tl;dr**: trying to use one app's user credentials on different other apps. Tried a solution, but I have hit a roadblock and looking for better ideas.

--

Say I have 3 different laravel 5.4 installation, and let's call them "App1", "App2", and "App3". Those 3 apps have completely different functions, and they could be used by the same users.

At the moment, the users are using App1, and their login credentials and information is resting in App1's database.

App2 is located on the same private network as app one, so when I wanted to give the users of App1 the ability to login App2 with their existing credentials, I went this way:

1. Created a database connection in App2 that points to App1's database, using the private IP address of App1;
2. Used this new connection on the User model of App2 and bam, it worked.

But now I want to offer the same possibility with App3, but it's not located within the same network and I'm starting to see the shortcomings of my actual solution.

I could of course open the database connection of App1 to App3 specific IP address and keep the current setup, but I feel it's getting messy, and I guess it could be a security risk (I'm not knowledgable enough in this area to really know).

Then I'm thinking : API? Maybe Passport? Is this actually a road I should (and could) consider? If so, what would be an easy way to achieve it?

Comment: Easiest possibility would be to open the App1's database to App3 and use the same database for authentication. Now I assume you don't do that for some security reasons and my system administration knowledge is not good enough to help you with that. But that's exactly what I'm doing with 1 of my projects and it works well. To clarify "open database". What I mean is make it available to App3's server either by making it open to outside networks or making an exception for App3's IP.

Comment: @devk Yes, this is what I am doing with App1 and App2. The apps are located within the same private network, so I figured it would be less a security risk like this, but since App1 and App3 would have to communicate over the internet, I'm just not sure and like you, my sysadmin knowledge lack in that matter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look into a SAML solution that would allow you to share credentials across multiple apps and domains.

You can either use this [Laravel package](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2) or use vanilla [php-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml)